# Hide Command Prompt Window on Startup till start time end

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, startup

I am creating a windows application as a startup application. It will be started automatically on system startup. I want to delay the start time of my application for 5 minutes. For this i have created a custom script with below code and placed it in 'startup' folder.

```
@Echo off
TIMEOUT /T 300
start /b /d "{application path}" application
```

It will launch the application immediately after delay time completed. At this time command prompt window is appearing as below.

[image]

But for my requirement, this command prompt window must be hidden. How to do this?

Comment: [Run a batch file in a completely hidden way](http://superuser.com/q/62525/241386)

Comment: using VBS and `sleep` is better than running timer each second like `timeout`

Comment: Remember that start will take the first quoted argument as window title, so you need to insert a dummy arg "" just following start. In your  case  start isn't necessary at all. `CD /D "application path"& Application` should suffice.

Comment: check this - http://superuser.com/a/872858/62798

Answer (score 1):

Use a vbscript to do this.

```
wscript.sleep 300000
CreateObject("wscript.shell").Run "C:\folder\file.exe"
```

You have to use above function to hide a command prompt - you may as well put the timeout into the vbs script. One less file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using batch file, i have created a console application to start my application. Placed this console application in 'startup' folder. It automatically triggered and launched the application on system startup.